# Counter changing on both edges of clock

Tags: verilog

Below code is of up counter.  The code has no errors, but the graph has some errors like the count should be at only posedge but the count is counting even at the negedge of clk.

```
module countergate (clk,rst,current,next);
    input clk,rst;
    input [2:0] current;
    output reg [2:0] next;
    always@(*)
    begin
        if (rst==1)
            {next[2],next[1],next[0]} <= 3'b000;
        else 
        begin   
            next[2] <= ((~current[2])&(current[1])&(current[0]) | (current[2])&(~current[0]) | (current[2])&(~current[1]));
            next[1] <= ((~current[1])&(current[0]) | (current[1])&(~current[0]));
            next[0] <= (~current[0]);
        end
    end
    endmodule
```

TEST BENCH

```
`include "countergate.v"
module tb1();
reg clk,rst;
reg [2:0] current;
wire [2:0] next;
countergate DUT (clk,rst,current,next);
initial 
begin
    clk = 1;
    forever #1 clk = ~clk;
end
initial
begin 
rst = 1;
repeat (2) @(posedge clk);
rst = 0;
end
initial
begin
    #4;
    {current[2],current[1],current[0]} = 3'b000;
    #1;
    {current[2],current[1],current[0]} = 3'b001;
    #1;
    {current[2],current[1],current[0]} = 3'b010;
    #1;
    {current[2],current[1],current[0]} = 3'b011;
    #1;
    {current[2],current[1],current[0]} = 3'b100;
    #1;
    {current[2],current[1],current[0]} = 3'b101;
    #1;
    {current[2],current[1],current[0]} = 3'b110;
    #1;
    {current[2],current[1],current[0]} = 3'b111;
    #1;
$finish;    


end
initial
begin
    $monitor("%t :clk = %b , rst = %b , current = %b, next = %b", $time,clk,rst,current,next);
end
endmodule
```

[image]

Comment: This might not be the only problem, but for sequential `always` blocks you cannot use `always@(*)`. You need `always@(posedge clk, posedge rst)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5900011/matthew-taylor), if you want the count value to only change on the posedge of the clock instead of on both edges of the clock, you should use a sequential `always` block.  Change:

```
always@(*)
```

to:

```
always @(posedge clk or posedge rst)
```

You also need to change the testbench since it is driving the `current` input on both edges of the clock as well.  You should drive it only on the posedge of the clock.  Since you are incrementing the input, you can greatly simplify the code using a `for` loop.  Also, instead of using `#` delays, you can align it to the clock as you did with the `rst` signal.

```
integer i;
initial
begin
    repeat (2) @(posedge clk);
    for (i=0; i<8; i=i+1) begin
        current = i;
        @(posedge clk);
    end
    $finish;    
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly indicate that you want the always block to be evaluated at posedge of the clock:

```
always @ (posedge clk)...
```

If you also want to include an "asynchronous" reset, this means a reset that doesn't care about the clock cycle, you should also include it in the sensitivity list:

```
always @ (posedge clk, posedge rst)...
```

As this, the ***always*** block would trigger in both cases, in *posedge clk* or in *posedge rst*.